# What is the PHP equivalent to these lines in R?

Tags: php, r

I'm trying to port a script from R into PHP but not sure what lines 3 and 4 ([taken from the larger function discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708048/position-of-the-sun-given-time-of-day-latitude-and-longitude/8764866#8764866)) are doing. Looks like logical operations and array definition at the same time. Can someone please give me the equivalent in PHP?

```
cosAzPos <- (0 <= sin(dec) - sin(el) * sin(lat))
sinAzNeg <- (sin(az) < 0)
az[cosAzPos & sinAzNeg] <- az[cosAzPos & sinAzNeg] + twopi
az[!cosAzPos] <- pi - az[!cosAzPos]
```

Comment: pls provide some possible values for variables. we need to know their type

Comment: @Electronick -- To provide context, I just added a link to the source of the code to the post above.

Comment: @Electronick -- IIRC, the variables `dec` (declination), `el` (elevation), `lat` (latitude), and `az` (azimuth) will all be real numbers between -2*pi and 2*pi.

Comment: @Josh - would you mind explaining the logic in those last two lines??

Comment: @Owen -- Sure. `az` is a vector of real numbers representing angles in radians. The last line, says, essentially, "take those values of `az` whose cosines are not positive (the left-hand side); and replace them (the `<-`); with `pi` minus that same set of values". As an example, it will take a vector of numbers like `1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8` and return `1.3 1.4 1.5 1.541593 1.441593 1.341593`.

Comment: Thanks Josh. Will finish this tomorrow. Looking forward to testing it out. I'm hoping it compares well with the calculator at http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/AltAz.php

Comment: @Owen -- No problem. If you do get it up and running, you could update your post with a brief report on the results of the comparison. I for one would be interested to learn more about how it performs.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien - I ended up installing R on my XP machine and printing out vars from your script one by one till I got it exactly the same! I'm about to put it through some test coords/dates, but initial results look excellent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it looks something like:

```
if (0 < sin($dec) - sin($el) * sin($lat)) {
  if(sin($az) < 0)
    $az = $az + $twopi;
} 
else {
  $az = $pi - $az;
}
```

Only for lines 3-4:

```
if ($cosAzPos && $sinAzNeg) {
  $az = $az + $twopi;
}
elseif (!$cosAzPos) {
  $az = $pi - $az;
}
else {
  // leave $az value
}
```

according to commet I found in referenced post. But I not sure about accessing indexes in float

Comment: I think that `az[false]` was something like assigment to `null` and `az[true]` was basic assigment