# R function for position of sun giving unexpected results

Tags: r, geometry, astronomy, azimuth

I'd like to calculate the position of the sun given time, latitude, and longitude.  I found this great question and answer here: [Position of the sun given time of day, latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708048/position-of-the-sun-given-time-of-day-latitude-and-longitude/8823846#8823846). However, when I evaluate the function I get incorrect results.  Given the quality of the answer, I'm almost certain there's something wrong on my end, but I'm asking this question as a record of trying to solve the problem.

Here's the code for the function reprinted below for convenience:

```
astronomersAlmanacTime <- function(x)
{
  # Astronomer's almanach time is the number of 
  # days since (noon, 1 January 2000)
  origin <- as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 12:00:00")
  as.numeric(difftime(x, origin, units = "days"))
}

hourOfDay <- function(x)
{
  x <- as.POSIXlt(x)
  with(x, hour + min / 60 + sec / 3600)
}

degreesToRadians <- function(degrees)
{
  degrees * pi / 180
}

radiansToDegrees <- function(radians)
{
  radians * 180 / pi
}

meanLongitudeDegrees <- function(time)
{
  (280.460 + 0.9856474 * time) %% 360
}

meanAnomalyRadians <- function(time)
{
  degreesToRadians((357.528 + 0.9856003 * time) %% 360)
}

eclipticLongitudeRadians <- function(mnlong, mnanom)
{
  degreesToRadians(
      (mnlong + 1.915 * sin(mnanom) + 0.020 * sin(2 * mnanom)) %% 360
  )
}

eclipticObliquityRadians <- function(time)
{
  degreesToRadians(23.439 - 0.0000004 * time)
}

rightAscensionRadians <- function(oblqec, eclong)
{
  num <- cos(oblqec) * sin(eclong)
  den <- cos(eclong)
  ra <- atan(num / den)
  ra[den < 0] <- ra[den < 0] + pi
  ra[den >= 0 & num < 0] <- ra[den >= 0 & num < 0] + 2 * pi 
  ra
}

rightDeclinationRadians <- function(oblqec, eclong)
{
  asin(sin(oblqec) * sin(eclong))
}

greenwichMeanSiderealTimeHours <- function(time, hour)
{
  (6.697375 + 0.0657098242 * time + hour) %% 24
}

localMeanSiderealTimeRadians <- function(gmst, long)
{
  degreesToRadians(15 * ((gmst + long / 15) %% 24))
}

hourAngleRadians <- function(lmst, ra)
{
  ((lmst - ra + pi) %% (2 * pi)) - pi
}

elevationRadians <- function(lat, dec, ha)
{
  asin(sin(dec) * sin(lat) + cos(dec) * cos(lat) * cos(ha))
}

solarAzimuthRadiansJosh <- function(lat, dec, ha, el)
{
  az <- asin(-cos(dec) * sin(ha) / cos(el))
  cosAzPos <- (0 <= sin(dec) - sin(el) * sin(lat))
  sinAzNeg <- (sin(az) < 0)
  az[cosAzPos & sinAzNeg] <- az[cosAzPos & sinAzNeg] + 2 * pi
  az[!cosAzPos] <- pi - az[!cosAzPos]
  az
}

solarAzimuthRadiansCharlie <- function(lat, dec, ha)
{
  zenithAngle <- acos(sin(lat) * sin(dec) + cos(lat) * cos(dec) * cos(ha))
  az <- acos((sin(lat) * cos(zenithAngle) - sin(dec)) / (cos(lat) * sin(zenithAngle)))
  ifelse(ha > 0, az + pi, 3 * pi - az) %% (2 * pi)
}

sunPosition <- function(when = Sys.time(), format, lat = 46.5, long = 6.5) 
{    
  if(is.character(when)) when <- strptime(when, format)
  time <- astronomersAlmanacTime(when)
  hour <- hourOfDay(when)

  # Ecliptic coordinates  
  mnlong <- meanLongitudeDegrees(time)   
  mnanom <- meanAnomalyRadians(time)  
  eclong <- eclipticLongitudeRadians(mnlong, mnanom)     
  oblqec <- eclipticObliquityRadians(time)

  # Celestial coordinates
  ra <- rightAscensionRadians(oblqec, eclong)
  dec <- rightDeclinationRadians(oblqec, eclong)

  # Local coordinates
  gmst <- greenwichMeanSiderealTimeHours(time, hour)  
  lmst <- localMeanSiderealTimeRadians(gmst, long)

  # Hour angle
  ha <- hourAngleRadians(lmst, ra)

  # Latitude to radians
  lat <- degreesToRadians(lat)

  # Azimuth and elevation
  el <- elevationRadians(lat, dec, ha)
  azJ <- solarAzimuthRadiansJosh(lat, dec, ha, el)
  azC <- solarAzimuthRadiansCharlie(lat, dec, ha)

  data.frame(
      elevation = radiansToDegrees(el), 
      azimuthJ  = radiansToDegrees(azJ),
      azimuthC  = radiansToDegrees(azC)
  )
}
```

If I run:

```
sunPosition(when = Sys.time(),lat = 43, long = -89)
```

The result is:

```
  elevation azimuthJ azimuthC
1 -24.56604 55.26111 55.26111
```

Sys.time() gives:

```
> Sys.time()
[1] "2016-09-08 09:09:05 CDT"
```

It's 9am, and the sun is up.  Using http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/solcalc/ I get an azimuth of 124 and elevation of 38, which I think is correct.

I thought maybe it was an issue with the code, but I also tested Josh's original sunPosition function from the above answer and got the same results.  My next thought is that there is an issue with my time or timezone.

---

testing the winter solstice as done in the above question, still gives the same results they found and looks correct:

```
testPts <- data.frame(lat = c(-41,-3,3, 41), 
                      long = c(0, 0, 0, 0))

time <- as.POSIXct("2012-12-22 12:00:00")

sunPosition(when = time, lat = testPts$lat, long = testPts$long)

elevation azimuthJ azimuthC
1  72.43112 359.0787 359.0787
2  69.56493 180.7965 180.7965
3  63.56539 180.6247 180.6247
4  25.56642 180.3083 180.3083
```

When I do the same test, but change the longitude (-89), I get a negative elevation at noon.

```
testPts <- data.frame(lat = c(-41,-3,3, 41), 
                      long = c(-89, -89, -89, -89))

time <- as.POSIXct("2012-12-22 12:00:00 CDT")

sunPosition(when = time, lat = testPts$lat, long = testPts$long)

      elevation azimuthJ azimuthC
1  16.060136563 107.3420 107.3420
2   2.387033692 113.3522 113.3522
3   0.001378426 113.4671 113.4671
4 -14.190786786 108.8866 108.8866
```

Comment: I just checked all 24 timezones for the timestamp `2016-09-08 09:09:05 CDT`, and none of them gave an `azimuthJ` of `55.26` or an `azimuthC` of `55.26`.  In fact, the two values were always different.  So I think there may be a bug in your code.

Comment: hmm, good to know.  Did you run the code as I pasted it and get the same bad results?

Comment: I get results similar to yours, @Tedward :  `sunPosition(when = as.POSIXct("2016-09-08 09:09:05 CDT"),lat = 43, long = -89)` yields `-24.43463 55.45186 55.45186`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the core code found in the linked post **if** the input `when` is given in UTC. The confusion was that the OP entered the wrong `Time Zone` in the website for the `Sys.time()` of `2016-09-08 09:09:05 CDT`:

> Using http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/solcalc/ I get an azimuth of 124 and elevation of 38, which I think is correct.

[image]

The correct `Time Zone` to input into the NOAA website is `-5` for `CDT` ([see this website](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cdt)), which gives:

[image]

Calling `sunPosition` with the time adjusted to UTC gives a similar result:

```
sunPosition(when = "2016-09-08 14:09:05", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",lat = 43, long = -89)
##  elevation azimuthJ azimuthC
##1  28.08683 110.4915 110.4915
```

Now, the code does not do this conversion to UTC. One way to do that is to replace the first line in `sunPosition`:

```
if(is.character(when)) when <- strptime(when, format)
```

with

```
if(is.character(when)) 
  when <- strptime(when, format, tz="UTC")
else
  when <- as.POSIXlt(when, tz="UTC")
```

We can now call `sunPosition` with:

```
sunPosition(when = "2016-09-08 09:09:05-0500", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z",lat = 43, long = -89)
##  elevation azimuthJ azimuthC
##1  28.08683 110.4915 110.4915
```

to get the same result. Note that we **NEED TO** specify the offset from UTC in the string literal and in the `format` (`%z`) when calling `sunPosition` this way.

With this change `sunPosition` can be called with `Sys.time()` (I'm on the East Coast):

```
Sys.time()
##[1] "2016-09-08 12:42:08 EDT"
sunPosition(Sys.time(),lat = 43, long = -89)
##  elevation azimuthJ azimuthC
##1  49.24068 152.1195 152.1195
```

which matches the NOAA website

[image]

for `Time Zone` = `-4` for `EDT`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer aichao!  As you correctly identified, my key confusion was the failure to convert to UTC.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with longitude.  If I set longitude to 0 and latitude to my latitude and time to my time, I get correct values for elevation and azimuth.

```
> time <- Sys.time()
> time

[1] "2016-09-08 12:07:35 CDT"

> sunPosition(when = time, lat = 43, long = 0)

 elevation azimuthJ azimuthC
1  52.36687 184.1056 184.1056
```

It seems to me that longitude is longitude relative to your position.  I'm not an expert on this topic, but in a way it makes sense that longitude would be this way since it doesn't have much effect on solar position.  A person at a given latitude at a given local time will see the sun in the same position in the sky as someone else at a different longitude, but same latitude and local time (ignoring complications of timezones being binned regions with discrete boundaries and the earth moving around the sun).

Maybe I didn't read the question or the function well enough, but it is unexpected that longitude behaves this way.

---

edit: 
Reading @aichao's answer shows why setting latitude to zero and making the time local time works approximately.  However, I don't think this will be very accurate.